# Switching Micro-controller from Adapter power to Battery

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, battery-operated

Currently I am running my micro-controller boards with power adapter(AC to DC).

Now I am developing a system which senses AC power and sends me some signal when AC power is gone.

The problem is I am running my board with the AC power(through adapter) which I am sensing. So, I need to switch to battery power( as backup ) instantly when AC power is gone making sure my board doesn't turn off while switching.

I am not sure how it should be done.

Comment: @LeonHeller this is not the duplicate of what you are interpreting, I am  on 5 volts and I am not using any relay to switch for switching

Comment: Why put relay in the tags, then?

Comment: @LeonHeller I thought it could done by using relay and a capacitor .

Comment: @LeonHeller Also I don't have options on my board , I have only one option of adapter I want to integrate that option only

Comment: You are not making sense Saad, you say you "don't have options" then you say you "have only one option" then you want to "integrate that option". What are you trying to achieve? Please be clear.

Comment: @Andyaka I want to make a UPS type of circuit to power my board

Comment: I am also voting to close because the answers marked as duplicated should give some directions. You can ask a **specific** question later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simple solutions is using Diode-OR ([related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/oring-power-supplies-diode-or-mosfet)), you only need one-one serial diode after the two power lines, as follows:

[image]

As long as the voltage from the battery is less than the voltage from the AC/DC adapter D1 diode will conduct and as soon as the voltage from the AC/DC source disappears D1 will close and D2 will conduct.

Disadvantage is that you lose voltage over the diodes (diode forward voltage drop), I do not know if it is a problem in your case or your sources are high enough.

This was one a simple option which needs only two additional component, but you can use specific IC on supply switching purpose.

Example: [TPS2115A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2114a.pdf)

Typical application:
[image]

This solution need more component, thus more board-space, more expensive but here you do not lose voltage and it is more sophisticated.

There could be other ICs it was just an example as I said.