# BJT Pair on Voltage Regulator Output

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator

What's the purpose of the BJT pair on the output of this regulator?  Note: +VD is used to power several IC's.

It almost looks like a way to power +VD from two separate sources.  If so, I guess I'm not clear on what happens with the BJT's when both sources are applied.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a simulator to find out? Given that it's an incomplete schematic it might be best for you to do this.

Comment: What information is missing from the schematic and description I posted?  XPWR, XTMS, and XTDI signals run to a connector.  XPWR comes from a connector and is powered externally (+3.3 VDC I imagine).  +VD powers IC's on the board.  What more is there?  I guess I'd like to know how the emitter resistor value is calculated.

Comment: For a start, where does the full schematic originate. For seconds, where does XPWR originate? For thirds, where does +VD fully route to (including decoupling capacitors)? All together these would be good clues.

Comment: Sure thing.  Here's where the schematic originated (see page 4).  A general description is on the first page with a note on power for the adapter.  XPWR comes from the target card.  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/silicon%20laboratories_rial-debug-adapter-ug-1203458.pdf

Comment: Very strange way using Q2 to suppress possible negative voltages on Vd with XPR = connect to base to Gnd ofPNP but as you guessed it is a logical OR high to Vd.

Comment: It's a quick and dirty way of allowing the programming header to power the device.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Seems like a cheap way to do what this post was looking for. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/or-ing-power-supplies-diode-or-mosfet

Comment: Yes XPWR is an option not used here but for debug or programmer . It is a 3 to 3.6V input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pin 1 of the ribbon cable connector allows the target board to supply power to the serial adapter.

So it's probably better to "see" that section of the target board supply as the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKkFkf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note, above, that I've changed the viewpoint for \$Q_2\$ so that it is oriented correctly. The reason is that it's actually a BJT operated in *reverse* mode (active or saturated), which means \$\beta_{2_\text{SAT}}\$ will be rather low -- on the order of 1 or 2, maybe less. Meanwhile, \$\beta_{1_\text{SAT}}\$ will be much higher -- excessively convervative if estimated at 10, and much more likely operating okay nearer values of 40 or 50.

So there's quite a difference in the load currents that can be supported by that single resistor, \$R_2\$, when comparing the \$V_\text{D}\$ rail and the \$X_\text{PWR}\$ rail. And I think that's really the main point of this exercise. The connector pin on the target board is supposed to provide power to the serial adapter module. But it's an exposed pin and can be shorted or otherwise accidentally abused. If a short or an excessive load is placed on pin 1 (XPWR), then \$Q_2\$ just won't be able to saturate and the output voltage will drop to a safer level and so will its "collector" (reverse-emitter) current.

Meanwhile, \$V_\text{D}\$, which is safely and securely used by the target board itself (a known quantity and where fumble-fingers can't as easily screw things up) is being supplied via a higher-saturation-beta BJT, so it can handle a higher load current at its forward-collector.

However, \$R_2\$ does limit the total load that can be delivered either to \$V_\text{D}\$ or to the external pin to the adapter. So it's really a very nice way to handle things.

\$V_\text{BASE}\approx V_\text{CC}-700\:\text{mV}\$; available base drive current is about \$I_{R_2}\approx\frac{V_\text{CC}-700\:\text{mV}}{R_2=6.81\:\text{k}\Omega}\$.

*This is one of those cases that reminds us why maintaining proficiency with a variety of discrete BJT design concepts still remains relevant today.*

(A final note of smaller interest is that the voltage drop across the collector and emitter leads of a reverse-operated BJT, in saturation, is slightly less than it may be when forward-operated. So \$Q_1\$'s saturation voltage drop will likely be a little more than \$Q_2\$'s saturation voltage drop. Assuming sufficient base current is available for both BJTs, I'd expect the ratio of collector-emitter voltage drops between the two to be about a factor of 2 or 3. This has the nice effect that the voltage at \$X_\text{PWR}\$ will be closer to \$V_\text{D}\$ than \$V_\text{D}\$ is to \$V_\text{CC}\$. So those two rail voltages should be pretty close, so long as the load on \$X_\text{PWR}\$ is sufficiently light. I'm pretty sure that the designers of this circuit were aware of this, as well, and appreciated this side-effect, which came along for "free.")

Answer (score 2):

The bases of the transistors will be at a level roughly 0.7V below the higher of XPWR and the output of U1.  As such, that transistor will be on, while the one providing the lower emitter voltage will be off.  The practical upshot is that +VD will be powered by whichever line is higher than the other.  (There's an overlap case where both transistors are on simultaneously, but in that case there's no flow between U1 out and XPWR, since they're substantially equal voltages.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jonk (+1). **This is a dual OR current limited switch .**

The Current limit and max power dissipation in Q with hFE of 100 with short circuit protection would be 125mW

With  Ir2(382uA) = (3.3-0.7)/6.81k and short cct Vce=3V3 with hFE=100 then Ice= 38 mA

Thus as @jonk says makes a nice low current power limiter of  38mA*3.3V= 125 mW short cct. Pd in Q.

hFE tolerances withstanding, this is my assessment. **It is a dual sourced current limiter.**

Q never gets saturated fully with a short cct to Gnd on Vd.

Pin 1 is indicated as an external input 3~3.6V.