# Source selection Circuit

Tags: power, integrated-circuit

I am doing a project, in which there are two dc source a) 48V_ DC b) 48V_Reg to power the board.

If either of two is present, that power source will power the board.

If two power source is also present then it should select 48V_DC

Please let me know any IC or circuit in where I can implement above features.

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, you can use a diode selection circuit or pmosfets to select the source https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/or-ing-power-supplies-diode-or-mosfet

Answer (score 2):

This is a common requirement on telephone or wide area network equipment and servers.

The most straightforward way is just with a pair of diodes. No active devices required.

Solutions such as relays have the problem that there will be a power drop-out while switching over.

IC vendors such as Analog Devices have more sophisticated solutions that also support hot-plugging and avoid the voltage drop of diodes.

Comment: Can you please suggest any IC from Analog devices

Comment: "Analog Devices" is the name of a semiconductor manufacturer. "analog devices" means that. "Analog devices" causes confusion. Capitals matter!

Answer (score 2):

**Version 1**

Only one Schottky diode would be required.

[image]

It is to be ensured that the voltage of 48 V_DC is always slightly higher than that of 48 V_Reg, for the former to reverse bias the diode and predominate.

**Version 2**

Only one relay, with a 48 V DC coil, would be required.

[image]

Comment: In my application both voltages are exactly  same..

Comment: That should not be a problem in Version 2.

Comment: What if both voltages  are present

Comment: When both supplies are on, the 'NO' contact of K1 will connect  the output of 48 V_DC and its 'NC' contact  will disconnect the output of 48 V_Reg. That makes 48 V_DC the dominant supply.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I would recommend recognising 48V_DC as a logic signal to drive a single-pole double-throw switch such that if 48V_DC is 'on', the switch is connected to the 48V_DC terminal, and if 48V_DC is 'off', the switch is connected to the 48V_Reg signal.

Comment: Are you suggesting a manual switch - if yes it is not recommended.  If SPDT IC is used then for powering IC there is no power in board.   Please let me know if you can suggest any IC

Comment: @Puneeth Non-mechanical (is that what you meant by manual?) switch I've used recently: shorturl.at/nrQ02, although I'm sure there are versions with only one spdt switch out there, rather than the three present on this IC

Comment: Hey can you share the part number

Answer (score 1):

you can use a relay for that,
using the 48V_DC voltage as "digital signal"

when the 48V_DC is present, the relay is activated you have the 48V_DC voltage at the output,

the diodes make possible not to have a voltage drop during tansitions,

[image]

Comment: Hey can you please let me know which tool you used to draw above schematics

Comment: @Puneeth i use Cadstar (not my favorite)