# What kind of diode should I use?

Tags: diodes

What type of diode is best to use when I want to minimize the voltage drop in a 5V DC circuit with about 1500 milliamps in a THT form factor?

Comment: You ask as if you've already decided that a diode is the best solution for you. That might not be the case, there might be better solutions. So instead of asking for a diode (which is almost a shopping question, which are off topic) explain what problem you want to solve with that diode. There are solutions that have almost no voltage drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the minimal information given I would probably pick a low Vf Schottky diode rated for at least 10V and 3A. But beware the leakage current if it's important to you.

It's hard to recommend a specific part because we have no idea of your mounting preference, physical constraints, cost goals etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given your earlier question, look for “or-ing ideal diode”. These will have almost no forward voltage drop. They’re based on MOSFETs instead of diodes.

And here's a previous answer: [OR-ing power supplies (diode or mosfet)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/or-ing-power-supplies-diode-or-mosfet)