# Back to back P-MOSFETS for power sources OR-ing

Tags: mosfet, voltage-measurement

I am trying out a circuit that is supposed to allow for two power sources. It is based on the one at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/549083/35737

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcMF8W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Differences between my setup and the original.

- instead of D-G wires there are two 3.3k resistors
- R1, R2 = 2.2k
- R3 = 1 ohm
- V1 = V2 = 12V

Differences between my setup and the one above.

- SW1 and SW2 are relays
- M1, M2 = [DMP34M4SPS](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP34M4SPS.pdf)

There are also MCU interrupts for voltage based detection of whether V1 or V2 are active. I would say the detection works fine as my previous iteration with two OR-ing Schottky diodes
instead of the back to back MOSFETs worked well (aside for the big heat problem).

Now, for this circuit, my results are quite bad. The heating is no longer an issue but I am having detection issues like so:

- V1 active, V2 inactive: detection works fine
- V2 active, V1 inactive: I am detecting voltage on both sides, in a consistent manner. Where do I start with this ? No scope on my workbench :(

Comment: What does "detecting voltage on both sides" mean?

Comment: What about both V1 and V2 active? Seems you’re running XOR.

Comment: @Andyaka Means a pin change interrupt routine is executed on the MCU when either side gets low / high.

Comment: @winny For the moment this is not an issue. Not using the circuit like that.

Comment: Perhaps you should include the body diodes in your schematic.

Comment: @Finbarr is giving you a very big hint here as to what is wrong. ;-)